# CustomUserValidator class to allow using same email address, or same user name for authentication asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a websie and I'm stucking in testing authentication using different 3rd party authentication providers (Google, Microsoft, Facebook, Twitter .. and so on).
For all of them I need to use my email address; this is the one I've used to register and create my account.
I've started withh Goolge. Everything worked well. Than I moved to Microsoft, Facebook.

The problem now is that I get an error message telling me that:
1. my email has been already taken
2. my user name has been alterady taken

Resolving point 1. is pretty easy. Just set

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opts => {
            opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        })
```

in

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

To solve point 2 I was thinking about creating a CustomUserValidator class.

My class will look like that

```
public class CustomUserValidator : UserValidator<ApplicationUser>
{
    public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager,
        ApplicationUser user)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await base.ValidateAsync(manager, user);

        List<IdentityError> errors = result.Succeeded ? new List<IdentityError>() : result.Errors.ToList();

        //check username availability. and add a custom error message to the returned errors list.
        var existingAccount = await manager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);

        if (user.Email.ToLower() == existingAccount.ToString().ToLower())
        {

            return errors.Count == 0 ? IdentityResult.Success : IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray());
        }


        return errors.Count == 0 ? IdentityResult.Success : IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray());

    }
}
```

Any idea how to put in the code to validate against user name?
My idea was to pass a `IdentityResult.Success.Succeeded` when the current user's email matches with one already stored in the authenticated registered users. In my case, myself, as I'm developing the site.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I think you are registering the email in your application. This is not how 3rd party login works. 1) you have a login by a 3rd party, eg. Google, Facebook. 2) you need to register your application by Google, Facebook to get a ClientId. 3) You'll need to configure the 3rd party in your application (client/secret). What happens then is: on your website offer to login with 3rd party. Click the link, login on Facebook. If successful, user is redirected to you application because 3rd party identified you.

Comment: Hi Ruard, I've already got client/secret information from all aiuthentication providers I would like to use. I've already registered using Google. I've tried with Facebook and Microsoft. Registering is ok, but the website does not associate ny account in the Association Form

Comment: I've got the message "You've successfully authenticated with . Please enter an email address for this site below and click the Register button to finish logging in", but when I click on Register I'm prompted with the message "User name xxx@yyy.com is already taken"